# How to conditionally load plugins in PhoneGap / Cordova

Tags: ios, plugins, phonegap-plugins, ibeacon, cordova-plugins

I have an app built on Cordova 3.3 running this [phonegap-estimote plugin](https://github.com/kdzwinel/phonegap-estimotebeacons).

All works great on iOS 7 devices, but will crash on startup for any version previous.

I've tried using window.device.version on DeviceReady to bypass calls related to the plugin, but I think the app crashes on plugin initialization.

So my question: is there a way to conditionally load a plugin or prevent it from initializing?

Comment: Are you capable of updating the native code in the plugin?

Comment: Yes - and I tried modifying the objective c initialization code. In any event, I found the solution for my particular problem which was solved [here](https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK/issues/77). It doesn't directly answer the question above, but gets what I was really after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Wojtek Borowicz, I'm a community evangelist in Estimote.

Please note that Estimote SDK, for which the referenced PhoneGap plugin was built, is only compatible with iOS 7. You can however set some code within your libraries and the CoreLocation from 'required' to 'optional'

Comment: Yup, that's the solution I linked to. Thanks.